# Serving multiple domains with Django and Apache maps to one location only

Tags: django, dns, apache2

I am attempting to setup Django to serve multiple sites (in the below configuration I am using examples [www.domain1.com](http://www.domain1.com) and [www.domain2.com](http://www.domain2.com)). I have installed Apache2 successfully, configured wsgi.py successfully (or so it seems).

I have built my appache configuration file to attempt the following mapping:

[www.example1.com](http://www.example1.com) to serve from /var/www/mysite1
[www.example2.com](http://www.example2.com) to serve from /var/www/mysite2

DNS A records for both example1.com and example2.com point to the same IP address.

The trouble with my setup as it exists is that both domain1.com and domain2.com map to the Django residing at /var/www/mysite1, despite the fact that I have (in theory) set them to map to their respective locations.

My apache config files are as follows, and both of the files (mysite1.conf and mysite2.conf) have had symlinks made for them using a2ensite:

```
#/etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite1.conf

WSGIDaemonProcess mysite processes=2 threads=25 python-home=/var/www/mysite1/myenv1 python-path=/var/www/mysite1/myenv1/mys
ite1
WSGIProcessGroup mysite
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/mysite1/myenv1/mysite1/mysite1/wsgi.py
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain1.com
    ServerAlias xx.xx.xx.xx
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite1

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite1-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite1-access.log combined

    Alias /robots.txt /var/www/mysite1/myenv1/mysite1/static/robots.txt
    Alias /favicon.ico /var/www/mysite1/myenv1/mysite1/static/favicon.ico
    Alias /static/ /var/www/mysite1/myenv1/mysite1/static/

    <Directory /var/www/mysite1/myenv1/mysite1/mysite1>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/mysite1/myenv1/mysite1/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

#/etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite2.conf
WSGIDaemonProcess mysite2 processes=2 threads=25 python-home=/var/www/mysite2/myenv2 python-path=/var/www/mysite2/myenv
2/mysite2
WSGIProcessGroup mysite2
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/mysite2/myenv2/mysite2/mysite2/wsgi.py process-group=mysite2
WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain2.com

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite2-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite2-access.log combined
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite2
    Alias /robots.txt /var/www/mysite2/myenv2/mysite2/static/robots.txt
    Alias /favicon.ico /var/www/mysite2/myenv2/mysite2/static/favicon.ico
    Alias /static/ /var/www/mysite2/myenv2/mysite2/static/

    <Directory /var/www/mysite2/myenv2/mysite2/mysite2>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/mysite2/myenv2/mysite2/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

An example wsgi.py file looks as below, and is working correctly (ie loading from the correct location) when it does load:

```
import os
import sys
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
sys.path.append(BASE_DIR)
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite1.settings'
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite1.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

There are no errors being reported in either logs (/var/syslog/apache2/mysiteX.conf where x=1 or 2)

What am I doing wrong? How can I correct this so that domain2 starts to map to /var/www/mysite2?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you might need to move the WSGI settings into their respective VirtualHost sections.

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick! If you want to put something as an official answer, happy to tag it and upvote it, cheers!

Comment: No problem, glad it works.  I've added an answer for you. @Hayden

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `WSGI` tags need to be inside the `VirtualHost` block for their respective domain names.

E.g.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain1.com
    ServerAlias xx.xx.xx.xx
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite1

    WSGIDaemonProcess mysite processes=2 threads=25 python-home=/var/www/mysite1/myenv1 python-path=/var/www/mysite1/myenv1/mys
    ite1
    WSGIProcessGroup mysite
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/mysite1/myenv1/mysite1/mysite1/wsgi.py
    ...

</VirtualHost>
```